# How to stop an unknown amount of animations?

Tags: java, android, animation, android-edittext

)

I have an EditText on which I start a background animation, like this (Android):

```
EditText1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blinker);
EditText1.getBackground().start();
```

Now I have an ArrayList with lets say 10 EditTexts. Next I say: Let the first 4 blinking. So I start my animation like above in a loop or method or whatever.

Next I wanna stop these animations with a method like allAnimationsStop(). So each animation which is running should stop. I could use a loop which execute stop() for every EditText.

The problem is e.g. EditText5 didn't get an animation as a background because I set it just for the first 4. So at this point I get an error.

My question is how can I check that on a EditText an animation or just picture is applied?

Thank you:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the added background is an animation or not.

```
if(EditText1.getBackground() instanceof Animation){
    //call start or stop
}else{
    //leave it. this is not an animation
}
```

Or as a dirty solution, you can simply call the `stop()` method in a `try...catch` block and ignore the exception.